# How to attach a Python Notebook to a Databricks cluster's Init Script

Tags: python, databricks, init

I would like to have a python notebook stored as a Databricks Workbook loaded when I startup a particular cluster to that specified python functions are automatically loaded into any workbook that I am working on in Databricks. This is particulariarly important for schedule workflow jobs in which it adds time to run the outside command like this each time:

```
%run /COMPANY/Functions/Read
```

I have tried all of the following in the cluster's advanced options init script for Workspaces and none of them seem to work. I could use help getting this formatted correctly:

- /COMPANY/Functions/Read
- COMPANY/Functions/Read
- /COMPANY/Functions/Read.dbc
- /COMPANY/Functions/Read.py
- workspace:/COMPANY/Functions/Read
- /WORKSPACE/COMPANY/Functions/Read

Comment: @DileeprajnarayanThumula, AWS databricks